# GTFS import and pgRouting

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, routing, general-transit-feed-specification

I found the gtfs2pgrouting project from pgRoutings' GitHub page. But it's three years old and doesn't work with the (current) full GTFS specification as it looks.

First of all I would like to know if there is a simple way to route GTFS data (preferably inside PostgreSQL). I think OpenTripPlanner is too full blown for me. And it has problems with huge/multiple graphs as it looks.

Otherwise I would write my own solution, connected to my already imported OSM/pgRouting instances.

So part two: Are there any fully functional import tools to get GTFS data into PostgreSQL 9.3+ that employ PostGIS 2+?

Comment: gtfs2pgrouting was written as part of a Google Summer of Code project, but as you said, it's already a few years old. The pgRouting project would appreciate, if someone could take care of gtfs2pgrouting and make it even better. It shouldn't be so difficult, but requires either time or funding.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is currently no real alternative to OTP, esp. for supporting big networks. See also: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GTFS